# Title is on another height than ion-buttons in toolbar

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

i have problems with LOGO as title in IOS. In android, logo and buttons are on the same height. In the IOS LOGO is higher than buttons.

My code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="navCtrl.pop()" class="backbutton">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      <img alt="logo" height="20" src='assets/img/logo.png'>
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <custom-buttons></custom-buttons>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image]

--EDIT

CSS:

```
ion-title img {
  height: 20px;
}

ion-title {
  background-color: #121d27;
  color: #fff;
}

ion-buttons button[icon-only].backbutton {
  color: white;
}

.toolbar-background{
  background-color: #121d27;
}
```

Comment: could you provide the CSS please?

Comment: Yep, i added CSS into post

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sure if you set the property `vertical align` on all three items in `<ion-toolbar>` you can align all three vertically.

Just put:

```
ion-title, ion-buttons {
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

Comment: do you have a set `height` for this nav bar?

Comment: as you can see in my code, im not using <ion-navbar>.

As i remember, the default height of header is 44px, but i didn't change it.
Everything i have in APP.SCSS I paste in the post (plus your code)

Comment: did you try setting the `line-height` of your elements to `44px`?